# Perform addition concisely on class properties in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

So, I've been hacking on Kotlin and I recently coded this class that represents an amount in British pence according to the coins used:

```
data class PenceAmount(
    val one: Int,
    val two: Int,
    val five: Int,
    val ten: Int,
    val twenty: Int,
    val fifty: Int,
    val pound: Int,
    val twoPound: Int) {}
```

I wanted to be able to add two `PenceAmount` objects using the `+` operator so I did this:

```
operator fun plus(other: PenceAmount) : PenceAmount {
    return PenceAmount(this.one + other.one,
            this.two + other.two,
            this.five + other.five,
            this.ten + other.ten,
            this.twenty + other.twenty,
            this.fifty + other.fifty,
            this.pound + other.pound,
            this.twoPound + other.twoPound)
}
```

**My Question is:** Is there a way to iterate on the properties of an object to perform this addition concisely?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Perhaps start by storing the coins (and their counts) in a `Map`.

Comment: @AjahnCharles I thought of that at first but I really needed a POJO to represent my amounts, so I couldn't afford the increased overhead :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I would have written the function `plus` in the same way as you've done. But, I'll give you the answer to your question **even if I don't recommend to apply it in this case.**

> Is there a way to iterate on the properties of an object to perform
>   this addition concisely?

Yes, you can do it using **reflection**.

First, you have to include the *kotlin-reflect* dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.51"
```

Then, you can rewrite the operation function `plus(PenceAmount)` as follows:

```
operator fun plus(other: PenceAmount): PenceAmount {
    // Get the primary constructor.
    val primaryConstructor = PenceAmount::class.primaryConstructor ?:
            throw NullPointerException("The primary constructor can't be found.")

    // Get the properties before the loop.
    val memberProperties = PenceAmount::class.declaredMemberProperties

    // Loop on each constructor parameter and get the new
    // values used to create a new instance of PenceAmount.
    val newValues = primaryConstructor.parameters.map { parameter ->
        // Find the KProperty with the same name of the parameter (because we are in a data class).
        val property = memberProperties.first { it.name == parameter.name }
        // Sum the amount.
        property.get(this) as Int + property.get(other) as Int
    }
    // Create a new instance of PenceAmount with the new values.
    return primaryConstructor.call(*newValues.toTypedArray())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That looks so overkill though, your suggestion of not using it is definitely on point. I guess we're still some way off a language that can figure this kind of operation out without being told how to do it!